# When simmering black eyed peas, should the water turn brown?

Tags: beans

I'm simmering black eyed peas for the first time. I rinsed them *very* thoroughly, covered with clean water, and simmered.

The water they're in has turned dark brown. Is that normal?

Answer (score 4):

I am sure it is; the pigments in beans can be soluble in water, and there will be more time for them to dissolve when you cook the beans.

If you cook black beans, the water turns nearly black.

Answer (score 1):

Been eating and cooking blackeye peas for over 30 years and yes, the water turning brown is quite normal.  Still enjoying them.